# What's the problem with Delphi Rest Client components

Tags: rest, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm trying to consume a simple API just for test, but it doesn't work using Delphi Rest Clients components.

Call to API works using browser and Postman without any configuration. The URL is https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/status

First I've tried use the tool "Rest Debugger" and it returns nothing.

So I tried to use the trio of REST CLIENT components by doing the following steps:

1. Created a new project;
2. Added `TRestClient`, `TRestRequest` and `TRestResponse` components;
3. Configured `BaseURL` from `TRestClient` as "https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/status"
4. Clicked the right mouse button on the `TRESTRequest` component
5. Hit `Execute...` command

It returns the following error:

> Error receiving data: (12152) the server returned an invalid or unrecognized response

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The json marshalling is very poor to begin with. And I  don't know how it's in Rio, but in previous versions [support for gz compressed API was poor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607506/trestclient-trestrequest-incorrectly-decodes-gzip-response) as well.

Comment: Funny that using the URL https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/511529?site=stackoverflow it works.

Comment: Jup, apparently [they fixed that in 10.1 Berlin](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9855)